# tmux outputs "unknown command: copy-mode" at start

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, tmux

My .tmux.conf looks like the following:

```
# enable aliases in tmux
set-option -g default-command /bin/bash
bind-key -n C-a send-prefix

# split panes using | and -
bind | split-window -h
bind - split-window -v
unbind '"'
unbind %

# Scroll using PgUp and PgDown
bind -temacs-edit -n PageUp copy-mode -u
bind -temacs-copy -n PageUp halfpage-up
bind -temacs-copy -n PageDown halfpage-down

# reload config file
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf

# switch panes using Alt+Arrowkeys
bind -n M-Left select-pane -L
bind -n M-Right select-pane -R
bind -n M-Up select-pane -U
bind -n M-Down select-pane -D

# enable mouse-mode
set -g mouse-select-window on
set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mode-mouse on

# rename windows automatically - will be changed eventually
set-option -g allow-rename on

# set the first window index to 1 to match keyboard layout
set -g base-index 1

# set scrollback-buffer
set -g history-limit 10000

# Ctrl+Pg(Up/Down) to switch windows
bind-key -n C-PageDown select-window -t :+
bind-key -n C-PageUp select-window -t :-

# No delay for escape key press
set -sg escape-time 0

# THEME
set -g status-bg blue
set -g status-fg white
set -g window-status-current-bg blue
set -g window-status-current-fg white
set -g window-status-current-attr bold
set -g status-interval 15
set -g status-left-length 30
set -g status-left '#[fg=yellow][#(whoami)@#(uname -n)]'
set -g status-right '#[fg=yellow]#(cut -d " " -f 1-3 /proc/loadavg)#[default] #[fg=white]%H:%M#[default]'
```

According to various sources, including the tmux man-page the command "copy-mode" should get tmux to enter the copy-mode. For some reason this doesn't work:
When opening tmux I get the error `/home/max/.tmux.conf:12: unknown command: copy-mode` and when trying to enter the copy-mode using the PageUp-Key (after spamming the console by using the `nmap` command) nothing happens. When in copy-mode however I can use the PageUp-Key to jump half a page up.

Answer (score 0):

To enter `copy-mode` by pressing <kbd>PgUp</kbd> (without the prefix), you need this instead:

```
bind-key -T root PageUp copy-mode -u
```

From the manpage section on `bind-key`:

> The root table is used for keys pressed **without the prefix key**:
>   binding ‘c’ to new-window in the root table (not recommended) means a
>   plain ‘c’ will create a new window. -n is an alias for -T root.

Comment: When reloading the config I get `/home/max/.tmux.conf:12: usage: bind-key [-cnr] [-t key-table] key command [arguments]` and pressing PageUp doesn't do anything.

Comment: Well, looks like you have an older version. Maybe ``-t root`` instead? You'll have to look at the manpage for your version of tmux in the ``bind-key`` section.

Comment: I changed it to `bind-key -t root PageUp copy-mode -u` because my manpage suggests to do so, but I get `unknown key table: root` in the same line. When replacing root with emacs-edit the previous error occurs again.
If I understand correctly this boils down to "how is the default mode called in my version of tmux?" (my tmux version is 1.8).

Comment: I suggest upgrading to version 2. Version 1 doesn't have a separate root key table, so if you bind PgUp with -n to copy-mode, you can't have a separate binding for the emacs-copy table.